# Pass a function in onFocusChange Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this function :

```
void _CalculTotal() {
total = total + double.tryParse(widget.controllers.last.text);
setState(() {
  totalDocument.text = total.toString();
});
```

}

I want to pass it in `onFocusChange` when the user loses the focus .

```
Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.7,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            child: Focus(
              onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) 
               widget.Prix;
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                enabled: true,
                controller: widget.fieldController4,
                validator: widget.fieldValidator,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  hintText: "${widget.content4}",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 190, 190),
                      fontSize: 14),
                  fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

this is my widget constructor :

```
class InputRefNomProduit extends StatefulWidget {

final VoidCallback Prix;
InputRefNomProduit(
  {
      // ...
  this.Prix
  });
```

and this is where I'm calling the widget in my main screen :

```
InputRefNomProduit(
      // ..
      Prix: _CalculTotal,
      )
```

I'm not getting any error but the function won't work .(I tried to print a message when the function is triggered but the message won't show up , so the call wasn't successful).
If I put a simple print statement here , It works :

```
onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) 
           print("Hello");
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a focusNode like this

```
 FocusNode firstFocusNode = FocusNode();
```

In your initState add a listener of the focusNode and call function onFocus change

```
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   firstFocusNode.addListener(() {
  if (!firstFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      _CalculTotal();
  } 
 });
}
```

Here's the textFormField.

```
TextFormField(
        focusNode: firstFocusNode,
        onFieldSubmitted: (v) {
          FocusScope.of(context)
              .requestFocus(firstFocusNode);
        }, //your other properties 
 )
```

Let me know if it works for you.